# ListView adapter does not behave as expected

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm having a problem that is making me crazy. Every adapters that I've made before with the same code worked perfectly, however this one don't. Calling .notifyDataSetChanged() don't work and it just call getView() 1 time, don't matter how many items the List has.

Summing up: the adapter don't refresh the listview when I call .notifyDataSetChanged() and it is calling getView() just 1 time.

Adapter code:

```
public class ObstacleListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Obstacle> feedItems;

public ObstacleListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Obstacle> feedItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.feedItems = feedItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return feedItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.obstacle_list_row, null);


    TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.obstacle_text);

    Obstacle obstacle = feedItems.get(position);

    text.setText(obstacle.getName()+" à "+
            calculationByDistance(MapsActivity.MY_LOC,new LatLng(obstacle.getLatitude(),obstacle.getLongitude()))+" metros");


    return convertView;
}

public double calculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
    int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
    double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
    double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
    double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
    double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
            * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
    double valueResult = Radius * c;
    double km = valueResult / 1;
    DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
    int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
    double meter = valueResult % 1000;
    int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
    Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
            + " Meter   " + meterInDec);

    return kmInDec*1000;
}
```

Activity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    ctx = this;
    dbOperations = new DatabaseOperations(ctx);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_item);
    adapter = new ObstacleListAdapter(this, obstacleList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    obstacleList = dbOperations.listAllObstacles();
    for(int i=0;i<obstacleList.size();i++){
        LatLng marker = new LatLng(obstacleList.get(i).getLatitude(), obstacleList.get(i).getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(marker).title(obstacleList.get(i).getName()));
    }

    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

            //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
            //CameraUpdate center =
            //      CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 20);

            //mMap.moveCamera(center);
            MY_LOC = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            obstacleList.clear();
            obstacleList = dbOperations.listAllObstacles();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

    setMapIfNeeded();

}
```

Comment: When you log getICount(), how many items are there?

Comment: Please upload your DatabaseOperations class file ..i think you got some problem in logic for getting whole data.

Comment: Try your luck by replacing `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.obstacle_list_row, null);` this line in adapter with `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.obstacle_list_row, parent, false);`

Comment: Zubair Ahmad Khan...there is not problem in inflating the xml file..problem is getting whole data in list. so be focus on issue...its not luck depends.

Comment: how many items you have in your feedItems list??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your activity with:

```
obstacleList.clear();
obstacleList = dbOperations.listAllObstacles();
```

You're essentially changing obstacleList to this new list (which won't propagate through to the list adapter.

Instead, what you should do is:

```
obstacleList.clear()
obstacleList.addAll(dbOperations.listAllObstacles());
```

Comment: Same problem above the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Change your extend class to `ArrayAdapter<Obstacle>`.

Comment: OP implemented all the methods of BaseAdapter correctly. This is in no way an answer, it is a suggestion and can be added as a comment.